# htmlspecialchars() and htmlspecialchars_decode()

Tags: php

If I need to output a string like

```
<div><a>Some link</a></div>
```

that isn't retrieved from the DB, is it necessary to use

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars('<div><a>Some link</a></div>'));
```

or is it already safe to directly echo

```
echo '<div><a>Some link</a></div>';
```

to prevent XSS attacks?

Should I sanitize the text, where .;:'"{}[]$%#@!^&*()-_+=|<>?~ are allowed, before inserting it into the DB?
I mean, should I convert special characters before inserting them into the DB?

I'm using PDO.

Comment: If you directly echo it from PHP code, it is safe.

Comment: So the HTML is hard-coded in your code? Then no escaping is necessary.

Comment: fyi : XSS attacks is from client to server, not from server to client

Comment: @Martin Kabanen, so I can directly echo in HTML format and it will be safe?

Comment: Yes, it will be safe.

Comment: @lordkain — No. XSS attacks are from client to server to client. They can be reflected (where there is no database involved) or stored (where the data is placed in a database … and can display the bad data to a user other then the one who input it)

Comment: Let's say it would have been not safe. Are you really using the above code when handling unsafe data???

Comment: @Quentin you are absolutly right

Comment: @Quentin XSS can also happen without server involvement. This is called DOM based XSS.

Answer (score 2):

If you encode special characters and then immediately decode them, you end up back where you start with, so it is pointless.

If you take user input, store it in a database, take it out of the database and echo it to the page, then you are vulnerable to XSS attacks.

If you want to defend against it then either:

- Don't allow users to write HTML. Use `htmlspecialchars` on the data before you insert it into the page.
- Allow HTML, but run it through an HTML parser and white list elements and attributes that are both safe and acceptable to you.

If the HTML in the database comes from a trusted source (which means you have to authenticate the user, defend against CSRF attacks, and trust the person not to be malicious or an idiot), then you are safe to just output it without modification.

> I mean, should I convert special characters before inserting them into the DB?

Generally speaking, for any given format, you should escape data for that format immediately before inserting into that format. It saves problems if you need to present the same data in a different format late.

That said, running a whitelisting HTML parser over the data is a relatively expensive operation so you might want to create a sanitised version and store it next to the unsanitized version in the database.